# How to visualize cluster in R (Kmodes

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, visualization, k-means

this is my codes to cluster kmodes in R:

```
library(klaR)
setwd("D:/kmodes")
data.to.cluster <- read.csv('kmodes.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ';')
cluster.results <- kmodes(data.to.cluster[,2:5], 3, iter.max = 10, weighted = FALSE)
```

what's good library/reference to use to visualize cluster especially kmodes or the codes example?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this and let us know if it works per your expectation

```
plot(data.to.cluster[,2:5],col= cluster.results$cluster)
```

Comment: hmmm it's giving me a cluster graph but only the first 4 column name or could you explain me the red,green,black dot and why there are many square with 0.2, 0.4,0.6,0.8,1.0 . 

the plot result :http://imgur.com/a/Y46yJ

Comment: 1) Only 4 columns are there in plot because you have built cluster using 4 columns only (i.e.`data.to.cluster[,2:5]`; see the column filter here `2:5`). 2) 3 colors are your clusters (see second argument of `kmodes` & `plot`). 3) This is [pairwise plot](https://www.r-bloggers.com/five-ways-to-visualize-your-pairwise-comparisons/) where all columns has been plotted against each other. Hope it explains all your queries.

Comment: ah i see i still confuse about why there is green red and black color and what thoose means

Comment: ah i know how to read it by the way if there is many dot in the same place, could we show the total at that place cause my data is about 1 and 0 so kmodes should show the total number?

Comment: Is there a way to show total number in same cordinate. i mean when clustering if there are many value which is same as 1,1 (x,y) could we make r show the total number in 1,1?

Comment: 1) Regarding color coding, as I mentioned earlier these are clusters. You can consider red as 1st cluster, blue as 2nd and green as 3rd cluster. 2) For another issue (all points showing at same place) I think you should try `jitter()` function like `plot(jitter(as.matrix(df)), col= cluster.results$cluster)`.

Comment: i use this code
library(klaR)
library(cluster)
setwd("D:/Skripsi/TMC Polda Metro Jaya 2014-2016/----DATA FIX CLEAR 2014-2016/kmodes")
data.to.cluster <- read.csv('DATA KECELAKAAN TWITTER 2014 -2016 FIX -2(untuk k-means) - versi 3.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ';')
cluster.results <- kmodes(data.to.cluster[,2:5], 3, iter.max = 10, weighted = FALSE )
plot(jitter(as.matrix(df)), col= cluster.results$cluster)

Comment: but i get error in as.vector(x,mode) cannot coece type "closure" to vector type of "any"

Comment: `df` in my comment was the reference to dataframe on which you are trying to perform clustering. So let's try after replacing `df` by `data.to.cluster[,2:5]`. Hope this helps!

Comment: ah i tried use that too but the cluster looks like this :
http://imgur.com/a/tz2uI

could we get a cluster like this ?
http://imgur.com/a/Y46yJ 

but the dot in same cordinates show the total number in that cordinates

Comment: i use kmeans in visualize tools but kmodes is less popular and the tools dont have that feature.

i want something look like this : http://imgur.com/a/cuTlu or http://imgur.com/a/Y46yJ with total number in same cordinate.

dont know if R could do this/not , im new to R and still search how to do it

Comment: If KModes is based on modes (frequency), then expect that your cluster centers will converge to either 1 or 0 ... in your case. KModes is hard to visualize - I'll suggest you look at your cluster centers and use that to name/determine the profile of your clusters.